# CSS calculated width adds margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am stumped. I am using Bootstrap 3 static nav bar with a logo. I don't like how the responsive image works, so I would just like to calculate the size of the logo (image) to be 100% - 200px (width of hamburger toggle). I'm doing this so that the logo and hamburger can stay on the same "line" and don't increase the height of the navbar.

Here is my code snippet.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav">
                    Menu &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-2x fa-bars"></i> 
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                <img src="images/logo.png"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        ....
   </div>
```

In my CSS, if I add

```
.navbar-brand img{
    width:calc(100% - 200px);
    height: auto;
}
```

and then using Chrome Developer Tools, I see extra margin on the right. 
[image: screenshot in chrome dev tools]

But there is no extra (right) margin defined in the css.

[image]

Now, if i manually change the width in chrome dev tools to the calculated width (in this example it is 310px) -- then it works correctly.

[image: screenshot - manually changing to fixed pixels]

It seems like when I am using the calculated width, it adds a right margin, which causes the logo and hamburger to break to different lines. I have reviewed my CSS in Chrome Dev Tools and diff'd the two examples -- but can't find differences.

Any guidance as to WHY this is happening and how to fix it would be appreciated. Let me know if you need more code snippets.

Comment: Do you use normalise.css or reset.css?

Comment: No i didn't. But bootstrap uses normalize.css http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-normalize

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use float option.

i.e:

Use "pull-left" class in "navbar-brand" and specify the width

```
.navbar-brand {
   width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
.navbar-brand img{
   width: 100%;
   height: auto
}
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should try wrapping the entire nav element in "container-fluid" as the javascript for bootstrap, and the styles within bootstrap are likely stepping in between your nav elements, and adding "container-fluid" or (full size responsive container" to JUST your nav-header elements.

So begin by changing:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
```

To:

```
<div class="container-fluid"> <!--Move this around entire nav element oor eliminate entirely-->
 <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
```

Comment: When you manage the styles from within the browser, the page and CSS are cached.  So the changes you are seeing are temporary and will return on load to those you're posting above, which likely include the container-fluid being wrapped around the navbar-header element.  It will look find every time you alter it manually, and then bootstrap will realign it on load time after time.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I changed it so that the nav was wrapped in a container-fluid div -- It didn't change the result. Also, I understand that the page is cached and the changes are temporary. What I did to test my hypothesis is loaded the page with my CSS, opened a new window changed the width property of the image to the same (calculated) width as what was in the other window (eg. 310px) and I got the results that I wanted. <<< This is what I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an actual margin. When block elements does not extend to full width, dev tools shows the excess space as margin to show the layout.

[image]

In your case, please check if any value for `display` is inherited for this element.

Adding float will remove this highlight.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the width of the navbar-brand element. I changed the width of that to

```
width:calc(100% - 200px);
```

and then set the width of the logo to

```
width: calc(100% - 10px);
```

and that gave me the desired effect and I don't have the navbar-brand logo with a line break.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to solve the above div width problem. if it is **displaying** different in different browser then write for Moz `-moz-box-sizing:border-box`,

```
Webkit -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
```